# Javascript onclick change content of HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am adding new div when user clicks the blue button but everytime user click button, content of whole html is getting dissappeared i need a solution for it.
Also, is it possible to add an animation to it?

here is the demo just press blue button, type something and hit blue button again.

```
https://jsfiddle.net/61tbq4q6/2/
```

This is html part:

```
<input type="button" id="ebookParts" value="&#xf067;" class="custBut">

<div id="myContainerDiv">

</div>
```

This is the JS:

```
var i = 1;
$( "#ebookParts" ).click(function() {
      var container = document.getElementById("myContainerDiv");
    var html = document.getElementById('myContainerDiv').innerHTML;
    html = html + "<div class=\"col-sm-12\">"
    + "<div class=\"form-group\">"
    + "<div class=\"col-sm-6\"><label>Name</label><input class=\"form-control\" type=\"text\" name=\"display_name[]\"></div>"
    + "<div class=\"col-sm-2\"><label>Part</label><input class=\"form-control\" type=\"text\" name=\"part[]\" value=" + i + "></div>"
    + "<div class=\"col-sm-2\"><label>Pages between</label><input class=\"form-control\" type=\"text\" name=\"pages[]\"></div>"
    + "<div class=\"col-sm-2\"><label>price</label><input class=\"form-control\" type=\"text\" name=\"price[]\"></div>"
    + "</div>"
    + "</div>";
    container.innerHTML= html;
    i++;
   return false;
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by disappeared? Its not happening!

Comment: I mean the values of inputs are removing

Comment: i'll edit in a second

Comment: @squint can you check it again please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're saying the problem is that whatever the user manually typed into an input is disappearing, it's because you're destroying those inputs and replacing them with new ones when you do `container.innerHTML = html`. Your original assignment to `var html = ...` only captures actual attributes, not JS properties.

What you need to do if you're going to append new DOM elements using HTML, while keeping the old content, is to use [`.insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) instead of `.innerHTML`.

This way, instead of taking the existing DOM, converting it to HTML markup, adding more HTML to it, and replacing the old DOM elements with new ones generated from the HTML, you'll be simply creating the new ones from the HTML and adding them where you want them.

```
var i = 1;
$( "#ebookParts" ).click(function() {
    var container = document.getElementById("myContainerDiv");

    var html = "<div class=\"col-sm-12\">"
    + "<div class=\"form-group\">"
    + "<div class=\"col-sm-6\"><label>Name</label><input class=\"form-control\" type=\"text\" name=\"display_name[]\"></div>"
    + "<div class=\"col-sm-2\"><label>Part</label><input class=\"form-control\" type=\"text\" name=\"part[]\" value=" + i + "></div>"
    + "<div class=\"col-sm-2\"><label>Pages between</label><input class=\"form-control\" type=\"text\" name=\"pages[]\"></div>"
    + "<div class=\"col-sm-2\"><label>price</label><input class=\"form-control\" type=\"text\" name=\"price[]\"></div>"
    + "</div>"
    + "</div>";

    // The "beforeend" parameter inserts the new content inside the
    // container after the existing content.
    container.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", html);

    i++;
   return false;
});
```

Comment: Thank you. It is exactly what i am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you getting html, than changing it an then inserting again in your page. When you copying your html, you don't copying values, which already passed in inputs. Instead of this you need to use .appendChild() method, and you will also need document.createElement()

Comment: A little elaboration might help OP understand better.

Answer (score 0):

If you need only to add the div one time. Then check with a "if" before add the div.

```
var isAdded=false;
$( "#ebookParts" ).click(function() {
if(!isAdded){
//your code
}
});
```